# Excel Not Summing From SQL Import

Tags: sql-server, excel, sum

I imported a `SQL Server 2000` query into my `Excel 2007` workbook.  The data imported fine, but I can not get the `SUM()` or `SUBTOTAL()` functions to sum my data.  If I highlight the data and do text to columns, it will sum, but as soon as a refresh is performed the total is lost.

Is there formatting that I can to get these cells to `SUM()`

Preferrably non-vba

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a helper cell to convert the range of data you are hoping to sum into a number format.

The `=value(cell)` formula will convert the reference to a number:

[image: helpercell]

This will allow you to sum the range of helper cells to get your total or subtotal.